# Increase timeout to get push token in FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a client using our app that is behind a poor internet connection, and we're seeing timeouts from FCM when we try to get the token from FirebaseMessaging inside our application:

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:625)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4$com-google-firebase-messaging-FirebaseMessaging(FirebaseMessaging.java:392)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
```

We had some problems with other URL used by our client, and turns out that increasing the read/write/connection timeout from HTTP solve the problem, like this:

```kotlin
OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
```

I search for any configuration like this, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to increase the timeout while requesting a push token with Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Answer (score 0):

Replace proprietary Firebase implementation with your own or something more open and configurable like e.g. [UnifiedPush](https://unifiedpush.org/).

Signal, FairEmail, Element and Telegram FOSS has their own implementations which work well.

If you really need to use Firebase, don't make it as hard dependency. This timeout crash is also known for apps that work well until this exception occurres.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We already have our own notification implementation using SignalR and we also do pooling, to not rely 100% on FCM. But I was curious if rising the timeout would be possible anyway. Sometimes keeping documentation updated are hard, so maybe I was missing something that was not clear or not well documented.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).